# kohana 3.2 returns empty ORM result

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

I have problem with kohana 3.2 and Orm query. My code returns empty result but I am 100% sure that the row what I need is in table.

```
$product_desc = ORM::factory('product_description')
        ->where('language_id', '=', 1)
        ->where('product_id', '=', $product->id)
        ->find();
```

Normal sql  query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `product_descriptions`
WHERE `language_id` =1
AND `product_id` =7134
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Sql  returns  one row but Orm nothing. I tried for example:

```
 $product_desc = ORM::factory('product_description');
    $product_desc->where('language_id', '=', 1);
    $product_desc->where('product_id', '=', $product->id)
    $product_desc = $product_desc->find();
```

And many similar queries and still have no luck.

Kind regards,
Mark K.

Comment: What does `var_dump($product_desc->last_query());` tell?

Comment: Now I found answear. Thanks Thorsten.  I had overwritten in model find() and find_all() by second programmer.